# Solving an inequality with the floor operator

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Assume that $A$, $B$, $C$ are positive real numbers and that $I$ is a positive integer. How could I isolate $A$ in the inequality $\left \lfloor{AB/C}\right \rfloor \geq I$ ? The best I could do:

\begin{equation}
AB/C -1 \geq I \Rightarrow \left \lfloor{AB/C}\right \rfloor \geq I
\end{equation}

Thus, $A\geq C(1+I)/B$ is a sufficient condition for $\left \lfloor{AB/C}\right \rfloor \geq I$.

Comment: You could simplify your problem by setting $D:=B/C$ and just ask a question about $\left \lfloor{AD}\right \rfloor \geq I$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left\lfloor\frac{AB}{C}\right\rfloor \ge I$$
$$\implies \frac{AB}{C} \ge I$$

$$\implies A \ge \frac{IC}{B}$$

Comment: This is not an answer : you don't take into account the floor signs.

Comment: Well the floor of a number $\ge$ some integer which implies that the number must be $\ge$ that integer. I skipped the first line.

Comment: Or am I using the definition wrong? Correct me if I am wrong and I'll remove the answer.

Comment: Okay I see your point. But it doesn't seem very likely that you can pin down on a value of $A$ from just knowing the result of an inequality. For ex, and I am assuming I have used the definition of floor correctly, $AB/C \ge I$. What better can be said about $A$ then $A \ge IC/B$?

Comment: _In fact  you are right. I beg your pardon for having had a doubt_. The minimal value $A=\dfrac{IC}{B}$ when plugged into into relationship $\lfloor{AB/C}\rfloor \geq I$, one gets $\lfloor{I}\rfloor \geq I$ which is truebecause $I$ is an integer... which is the case. *

Comment: You embarrass me by apologizing to me, professor.